# set firestore security rule without auth

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

im building an ecommerce app , without AUTH or payment method (pay when u receive the item) ... so i will set the fav and bascket item in local storage (react native )
and for the order ,the user add it in firestore document (order doc)
i have two doc product and order
so i want to set my firestore security rule to allow read from product doc
and only write for order doc
and is it safe to do it like that

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do something like this i think because when you set the rules when you want, automatically after 30 days the rules will be changed again for secuirity reasons.

Also happy new year

(sorry for my bad english)